# Searching for a specific text in a column within an If statement

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am trying to find a specific text within a column using an if statement (shown below). Currently I'm searching each cell individually but would like to be able to shorten that code to search all of them.

```
If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R" & CustRow).Value, "Cradle") > 0 Then
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R5"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R6"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R7"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R8"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R9"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R10"), "PFC") Or
    If InStr(Sheet2.Range("R11"), "PFC") Or
    ....
 Then
    ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PdfTemplate16
Else: ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink PDFTemplateFile17
Application.Wait Now + 0.00001
End If
```

I would like to be able to search from row 5 to row 44 but really don't want to have that repetitive code in there.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You could use `Range.AutoFilter` or `Range.Find`.

Comment: I'll go look up how to use those. Not too familiar

Comment: I'm guessing you just want [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) with `LookAt:=xlPart`.

Comment: I am struggling to find out how to use the find function within this. 

So far its:

If .Find("PFC", LookAt:=xlPart) = True Then

but I'm not sure how to use it

Comment: What is your end goal? Can you say in simple words what you are trying to do?

Comment: End goal is just to have it look from R5 cell to R44 cell and see if the letters "PFC" appear in any of those cells

Comment: Are you looking for a full or partial match, e.g. in a cell only `PFC`... or perhaps `foo FPC bar`?

Comment: It would have to be exactly "PFC" in that order, but it could have other things around it such as "(PFC) Part Full Complete"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Range.Find`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find), and test if the `Find` actually succeeded to then take one action or another, something like the following:

```
Dim rangeToFind as Range
Set rangeToFind = Sheet2.Range("R5:R44").Find(What:="PFC", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)

If Not rangeToFind Is Nothing Then
   ' found a PFC cell, do thing A
Else
   ' no cell found, do thing B
End If
```

Comment: You could also use `WorksheetFunction.CountIf` with wildcards... there's several ways to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the together and just text once:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        s = Join(.Transpose(Sheet2.Range("R5:R44").Value), Chr(1))
        If InStr(s, "PFC") > 0 Then
            MsgBox "in there somewhere"
        Else
            MsgBox "not in there anywhere"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```